# AX 2012 initFrom methods

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

I understand that these initFrom(TableName) methods are to initialize fields in a table for related tables.  Where are they called from?  I want to follow this pattern but where do I call this method?

Every documentation on this pattern just tells me what I said above and no examples of using them.  I see examples of them being created.

Comment: Have you used cross-reference to see where the methods are used?

Comment: I've looked but I honestly dont' know how to really read the using table.  It gives me a large list of items from the table but it doesn't direct me right to the code.

Comment: I see I can click update then see references.

Comment: Yeah I can see it goes to things like modifiedField which appears to be an overridden method for when a field in a table changes.  Starting to make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxim Lazarev made a point about using the cross-reference tool.  I ignorantly did not realize that you had to update it on the table and then you can see what calls on that method.  That lead me to examples of it being used in overridden table methods like modifiedField.  I'm starting to play around but it looks like I can now use these initFrom methods to fill in specific data I need in forms whether it's directly in the table or in the actual form itself.

Answer (score 1):

The initFrom methods are to initialize the record based on another record. They are not called automatically, you can use them yourself 
though.

For example PurchTable.InitFromVendTable() sets all the relevant values from the vendTable to the (new) purchtable record. So if you want to create a Purchase Order and you have the vendor, you can use this method to set the correct values.

Comment: My confusion was where those were getting called from.  Even still I'm confused as there are some initFrom methods that are not used by anything.. they are just there.  Yet if I debug or call a info it does get called... but I don't know how or why some of them get called.